# Cant use DataTable.New

Tags: c#, datatable

Im trying to read a csv file using CSVTools library the code that I have to use to get the csv file in to a data table is,

```
var dt = DataTable.New.ReadLazy(filename);
```

But the problem is there is no ".New" keyword. When I write DataTable.New it shows an error. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include using statement on top of c# file as below

```
using DataAccess;
```

or use

```
var dt = DataAccess.DataTable.New.ReadLazy(filename);
```

Comment: I did include that as well

Comment: Thank you. I just figured that out. The latter works for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> Which means the `DataTable` that you are using is not belongs to the
>   expected `namespace`, use fully qualified name to get the correct
>   class.

You may have both `using DataAccess;` as well as `System.Data` in your using section, so by declaring DataTable alone will made compiler to assumes that it belongs to `System.Data`. By specifying the DataTable as `DataAccess.DataTable` you can help the compiler to find the exact class that you are looking for. This kind of specification is called fully qualified names. Make use of them and come out from that specified error. Your declaration will be like the following:

```
var dt = DataAccess.DataTable.New.ReadLazy(filename);
```